# Just Ignore the launcher activities defined in library

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-launcher

My Problem is one of my library has defined a launcher activity in their manifest. In this case when I install my apk, it creates two similar launcher icon with same name. I searched for ignoring the libraries launcher entries but still didn't find any solution.
Can we ignore all other LAUNCHER intent-filter(of library), while merging manifest.

Thank you.

Comment: remove launcher action of intent-filter from library

Comment: I am using the Gradle build system, and the libraries belongs to some third party. I have already told them to fix it, but they are taking time, so I want to solve it on my side.

Comment: One way is to import libraries into your project if their size is not large. Is it possible for you?

Comment: Yes I can import the library, but I think it is not suggested while using android studio and gradle build system.

Comment: But in your case you need to make some changes in the library so its ok to import it